# Mocking MQ connector in munit (mule 4) causing test to try connecting to the MQ and test fails

Tags: mule, munit

I am able to mock MQ connector in munit, no issues. When MQ is actually up and running, munit tests are successful, however if MQ is shut down, testing fails as it is not able to connect to the MQ. I want the munit tests to succeed even if MQ is down, it is already mocked, so not need to connect anyways. This happens only when publishing to a queue for me, but tests publishing to a topic are fine.

Any clues?

Comment: Which MQ connector? IBM MQ, AnypointMQ, JMS with ActiveMQ? which version of Mule, connector and MUnit? Share the XML configurations of the connector, the message processor in the flow and the MUnit in the mock.
In general you should provide all these details to have a chance to receive a response.

Comment: Hi aled, yes you are right. In fact I found out that the MQ I was calling was not mocked, another one was, and this is why the flow was trying to connect using the connector. So, it was more like a typo